# múltiplas imagens com editor wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, laravel, css3, wysiwyg

Estou usando um editor wysiwyg para gerar o conteúdo de textos para páginas dinâmicas de um blog que estou fazendo.

Como seria possível adicionar múltiplas imagens nos textos, as posicionando em determinado local do texto?

É possível fazer isso utilizando editor wysiwyg?

Comment: coloque o cursor no local dentro do texto clique no icone imagem, insira o endereço da imagem e pronto

Comment: Só que é uma a uma

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver galera, vou deixar a resposta aqui para ajudar quem caiu no mesmo problema.
Eu uso o laravel, então existe para o este Framework um gerenciador de arquivos que possibilita o gerenciamento, organização, seleção de múltiplas imagens entre outras funcionalidades! o link é:

https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager

é só seguir o passo a passo da instalação, após isso vá na opção "integration" no menu e lá ele indica alguns editores wysiwyg para a integração. 
eu estou usando o CKEditor e resolveu 100% o meu problema!

Sigam a documentação e sejam felizes.